# Entity framework core migration 'There is already an object named 'TableName' in the database'

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, ef-code-first

When I try to make migration I get error  'There is already an object named 'TableName' in the database'. My migratioin should alter table(I think so), but it tryes to create table with name tnat exist. 
I created database by Code-First. After I created Migration. Later I added some field and created SecondMigration and got this code :

```
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
            name: "Rating",
            table: "Person",
            nullable: false,
            defaultValue: 0);
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
            name: "Rating",
            table: "Person");
    }
```

Comment: This needs more details. In the meantime, you can check out the migration files generated inside the Migrations folder, to see what they do to your database. Or you can check the __EFMigrationsHistory table in your DB, to see if there are any mismatches with those in the Migrations folder.

Comment: I edited quastion